# equivalent of shell script's grep command in perl

Tags: perl

I have below syntax used in shell script-

```
imp_vol -u $undr_price -s $str_price -p $price -t $mat -c $iscall | grep "Black Scholes " | cut-d"=" -f2
```

Where `imp_vol` is an executable that prints something. What will be its equivalent in Perl script? For example:

```
imp_vol -u 110.5 -s 110.9 -p 0.005 -t 0.041 -c 1
    Underlying Price = 110.5
    Strike Price = 110.9
    Price = 0.005
    Time = 0.041
    IsCall = 1
    Black Scholes Vol = 0.0108141
```

So my purpose is to get the value of `Black Scholes Vol` in this case as `.0108141 in some variable,as I have to pass that variable in some function again.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a `grep` function in perl.  It takes an expression or a block as the first argument and a list of strings as the second argument.  So you could do this:

```
my @list = grep(/abcd/, (<>));
```

See also: [grep - perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)

In your specific case you can use the block form to extract the price like this:

```
imp_vol | perl -e 'print grep { s/\s+Black Scholes Vol = ([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)/$1/ } (<>)'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all "Black Scholes " like your `grep` would match

```
imp_vol -u $undr_price -s $str_price -p $price -t $mat -c $iscall | perl -ne 'print $1 if $_ =~ /Black Scholes .* = (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/;'
```

"Black Scholes Vol" exactly

```
| perl -ne 'print $1 if $_ =~ /Black Scholes Vol = (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

```
while (<>) {
    next if !/abcd/;
    # ...
}
```

Also, to replace cut, use [capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups), but I can't provide more code because I don"t know your data format.

Answer (score 0):

To execute the command, you can use [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Safe-Pipe-Opens) to get a filehandle from which you can read its output. You can then use a single regular expression to match the line and extract the value. For example:

```
my $cmd = "imp_vol -u $undr_price -s $str_price -p $price -t $mat -c $iscall";
open (my $imp, '-|', $cmd) or die "Couldn't execute command: $!";

my $extracted;
while (<$imp>) {
    if (/Black Scholes Vol = (.*)/) {
        $extracted = $1;
    }
}
close $imp;
```

The parenthesis create a [capture group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) which extracts the value into the special `$1` variable.

If you're able to pipe input instead of having to execute the command within Perl, the following one-liner would suffice:

```
imp_vol ... | perl -ne 'print $1 if /Black Scholes Vol = (.*)/'
```

Comment: @RobEarl-how about usage in current scenario-

Comment: See edit. You can either execute the command within the Perl script or pipe its output to the script.